# What is the maximun size of an inverse matrix that can be calculated using the Cofactor Method?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

During the third lecture of 18.02SC on MIT OpenCourseWare at 43:45 it is said that the cofactor method for finding matrix inverses is not suitable for large matrices. What is the limit size of a matrix used by algorithms using the cofecator method to calculate matrix inverses. The link of the lecture is the following: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/video-lectures/lecture-3-matrices/.

Comment: There is no *theoretical* limit to the size. It must have to do with need to do so many determinants of minors, or the storage space needed, or roundoff errors.

Comment: It is hard to do it by hand with matrices bigger than $\;6\times 6\;$ or something like that, but it is a rather simple recursive method that can easily be done with a computer and some minimal knowledge of  programming.

Answer (score 0):

There's no hard limit, it's just that the number of operations required grows more quickly than other methods.

Both determinants and inverses can be computed by row-reducing a matrix. Say that on one particular computer, this approach takes $1$ second for a $1000 \times 1000$ matrix. (It's enough to put the matrix in row-echelon form for a determinant, but for the inverse, we have to put a $1000 \times 2000$ matrix in reduced row-echelon form. So let's say the inverse takes several seconds, in the interests of fairness.)

The cofactor method for computing the inverse of such a matrix requires finding $1000^2$ determinants of $999\times999$ matrices, which will each take nearly the same time. You can still use the cofactor method for matrices of this size, but on the same computer, this will take about a million seconds, or over $11$ days. You would have to be very patient.